# Why are outputs of my UKF filter divided by 2pi and 2pi**2

Tags: kalman-filter

I am feeding a synthetic sine into a UKF filter and plotting the position,velocity and acceleration of the filter state.  To make velocity sensible, I need to multiply by 2*pi and for acceleration, by (2*pi)**2.

Why is this, and can/should I correct this so the filter states reflect actual velocity and acceleration of the sine wave?

Here are the plots, velocity and acceleration have been scaled.

[image]

Here is the python code:

```
from filterpy.kalman import UnscentedKalmanFilter as UKF
from filterpy.common import Q_discrete_white_noise
from filterpy.kalman import unscented_transform, MerweScaledSigmaPoints
import numpy as np


fs = 40.0
t = 2.0
f = 1.0

time = np.arange(t * fs)/fs

position = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * time)
velocity = np.cos(2*np.pi *f * time)
accel = -np.sin(2*np.pi * f * time)

def f_cv(x, dt):

    v = dt
    a = (dt**2) / 2
    F = np.array([[1, dt, a],
                  [0,  1, dt],
                  [0,  0, 1]])
    return np.dot(F, x)

def h_cv(x):
    return x[[0]]

from numpy.random import randn

std_x = .0001
dt = 1.0

zs = [np.array([p+randn()*std_x]) for p in position]

sigmas = MerweScaledSigmaPoints(3, alpha=.1, beta=2., kappa=1.)
ukf = UKF(dim_x=3, dim_z=1, fx=f_cv,
          hx=h_cv, dt=dt, points=sigmas)

ukf.x = np.array(\[0., 0., 0.\])
ukf.R = \[\[0.09\]\] 
ukf.Q = Q_discrete_white_noise(3, dt=1, var=0.02)

uxs = \[\]
for z in zs:
    ukf.predict()
    ukf.update(z)
    uxs.append(ukf.x.copy())
uxs = np.array(uxs)

#plt.plot(uxs\[:, 0\], uxs\[:, 2\])
#plt.plot(time,position,'go-',markersize=3,label='actual pos')
plt.plot(time,zs,'go-',markersize=3,label='actual pos')
plt.plot(time,uxs\[:,0\],'ro-',markersize=3,label='filter pos')
plt.plot(time,uxs\[:,1\]*2*np.pi,'yo-',markersize=3,label='filter vel')
plt.plot(time,uxs\[:,2\]*(2*np.pi)**2,'bo-',markersize=3,label='filter accel')
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x (t)=\sin(2\pi ft) $ is the position, then $v (t)=x'(t)=2\pi f\cos (2\pi ft) $ is the velocity and $a (t)=v'(t)=-4\pi^2f^2\sin (2\pi ft) $ is the acceleration by derivation rules.

Since you put $f=1$, $v(t) $ is scaled by a  $2\pi $ factor while $a (t) $ is scaled by a $4\pi ^2$ factor.